# storing strings in a mmap shared array? (C)

Tags: c, ipc, mmap

I am trying to store all filenames in the current directory in a shared array using mmap I can print all 9 files in the directory to the screen but when I try to store them in the array (shared_array) and print the array, all entries contain the same string (file.txt). Thanks in advance!

```
char **shared_array; 
shared_array= mmap(0,100*sizeof(char*),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON,-1,0);  
char * filename;

const MAXLINE = 80; 
char line [MAXLINE];

FILE *fp = popen("/bin/ls","r");

int i = 0; 
while(fgets(line, MAXLINE,fp) !=NULL){    
    filename = line;
    shared_array[i] = filename; 
    i++;        
}
pclose(fp);

int j;
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
    printf("\n%s",shared_array[j]);
}
```

Comment: Pointers in shared memory are not usually useful, because the addresses they point to are process-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
filename = line;
shared_array[i] = filename;
```

You're not actually copying the contents of your `line` array to `shared_array`.  You're assigning the address of `line` to each array element.  As a result, all array elements point to the same place, i.e. `line`, which will only contain the most recently stored value.

You need to allocate memory for each string you want to copy.  You could do that with `strdup`:

```
shared_array[i] = strdup(line);
```

But the problem with this is that you have shared memory containing pointers to non-shared memory.

You'll need to allocate space in shared memory for an array of strings:

```
const MAXLINE = 80;
char (*shared_array)[MAXLINE]; 
shared_array= mmap(0,100*MAXLINE,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON,-1,0);
```

Then you can use `strcpy` to copy into each array element:

```
strcpy(shared_array[i], line);
```

Comment: What's the point of putting pointers in shared memory if they point to non-shared addresses?

Comment: Note however that the memory allocated with strdup will NOT be shared memory (which seems to be the point of the original question). To get what the original poster wants is going to require packing strings into the shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

If MAXLINE denotes total number of strings each of size N :-

You cannot do this. It will give a very long string of size MAXLINE X N and will have to use offset to access substrings.

```
char (*shared_memory)[MAXLINE]  -> returns pointer to a string of size MAXLINE.
shared_array= mmap(0,100*MAXLINE,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON,-1,0);
```

You need to do this

```
char *shared_memory[MAXLINE] - This returns array of char pointers

for(int i=0; i<MAXLINE;i++){
shared_memory[i] = mmap(NULL,sizeof(char)*N,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
}
```

By doing this now you can access the strings by doing shared_memory[i].
Even though if each string is less then page granularity you will be wasting space but it will be easier to access.

or simply use

```
char shared_memory[100][MAXLINE];
```